# Installing Oracle database 10g, .oui not found

Tags: oracle, command-line, oracle10g, ubuntu-11.04, vagrant

I'm running a VM on Virtualbox through Vagrant, Ubuntu 11.04 server 64bit, and I need to install Oracle database 10g. I downloaded the package from Oracle and unpacked it. I went into the "database" folder that was created when I unpacked it and saw the runInstaller executable. When I ran it it got this error:

$ ./runInstaller: 63: /home/vagrant/database/install/.oui: not found

I went to the "install" directory and .oui was in there. What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by running this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```